# Do tier-splitting compilers exist?

Tags: compiler-construction

Do tier-splitting compilers exist? I'm interested in using one to automate the process of developing distributed applications. Microsoft's [Volta compiler](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/livshits/papers/pdf/volta-ieee08.pdf) looked promising a few years ago, but it appears to have gone the way of the dodo. Google has not been helpful for finding tier-splitting compilers.

Comment: OP appears to means,  "automatic distribution across multiple systems" by the phrase "tier-splitting".   The referenced article is helpful.